# Today() and Now() functions return Modified Date instead of current DateTime in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am using the "Today()" function as the default value in SSRS parameters to set start and end date ranges.  On the reports that have been deployed these parameters are returning the date the report was deployed (Modified Date) instead of today.  On text boxes or labels that use the Today() expression it is returning today correctly.

I know that i can get default values from a query (GetDate()), but I'd like to use Today() as it was intended...

Comment: You mean to say the default parameters are returning the date the report was modified as default dates ?

Comment: @Harry that is correct.  When I set the default parameter to be Today() or Now(), the report returns the modified date (which corresponds to the date the report was deployed) when run in our testing and production environments.

Comment: Today() returns midnight of today.  if you are setting the default parameter to Today() and the parameter is changing to another time it's because you are telling it to, either in available values of the parameter or some other way.  Today() is always midnight of the day it evaluates it, so if I ran in right now it would be 24th July 2018 00:00